# Onmousedown javascript not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to add a hover class to my html element with the following code:

```css
.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"
     onmouseover="$(this).addClass('shadow');"
     onmousedown="$(this).toggleClass('shadow');"></div>
```

The class will be added on mouseover but it won't be removed onmousedown.
Why?

Comment: This code works fine .... there must be something else interfering.  See here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQNzoM

Comment: only cause something works does not justify doing it.

Comment: Added an  example

Comment: your example works perfectly fine for me. i don't see the problem. you might want to state the browser that you are using.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 63.0.1

Comment: You're using `onmousedown` but are expecting it to fire when `mouseout` event is actually fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. Check this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWXV3Y8JXYTI

**Note:** `onmosedown` means when the mouse button is pressed! It's different from `mouseout`.

Comment: You're so right. Thank you for your help! Solved my problem.